# Function arc() doesn't render right in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am just making a little program with p5.js, but I found something weird. The arc() function doesn't seem to render correctly when the size is quite big.

Here is my code:

```
var ellipseSize = 200;
var strokeSize = 60;

for(var j=0; j<filteredTrees.length; j++){
  strokeWeight(strokeSize);
  var rad = 0;
  for(var i =0; i < filteredTrees[j].trees.length; i++){
    var element = filteredTrees[j].trees[i];
    var radBegin = rad;
    rad += (element.nbr/filteredTrees[j].rangeNbr)*(2*PI);
    stroke(element.color.red, element.color.green, element.color.blue);
    arc(width/2, height/2, ellipseSize, ellipseSize, radBegin, rad);
  }
  ellipseSize += (strokeSize*2);
  strokeSize *= 0.9;
}
```

And here is the rendered image, with black circles shwoing the correct alignment the arcs should have. Some arcs exceed their expected position, as you can see down there:

[image: Exemple]

Do you have any idea why it does this ?

Comment: can you make a fiddle??

Comment: More to the point, can you tell us what's **wrong** about the image? What should it look like instead? Can you simplify your sketch so that it only uses one arc that draws incorrectly, and tell us how it should draw instead?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what renderer are you using, the default 2D renderer uses beziers between the angles:
https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/0.6.1/src/core/p5.Renderer2D.js#L430

So, there is no way to increase the arc resolution...

I would recommend you to use sin and cosine to draw the arcs:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(200, 100);
  customArc(20, 50, 20, 20, 0, PI, PI/2);
  customArc(60, 50, 20, 20, 0, PI, PI/4);
  customArc(100, 50, 20, 20, 0, PI, PI/10);
}

function customArc(x, y, w, h, start, stop, resolution){
  beginShape();
  for(var i = start; i < stop; i += resolution){
    vertex(x + sin(i) * w, y + cos(i) * h);
  }
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/processing/p5.js/releases/download/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```